# Updating database table using HTTP PATCH verb in Postman

Tags: c#, http, azure, postman, http-patch

I am developing an Azure mobile service that contains a table controller with a Patch method:

```
public Task<User> PatchUser(string id, Delta<User> patch)
{
    return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
}
```

I am locally hosting my mobile service and want to test how Patch would work. I am using Postman to do that, but I keep getting HTTP Error 400 with the following response:

> {   "message": "The HTTP request did not include a valid entity body.
>   Please ensure there is an entity body and an associated Content-Type
>   header present in the request." }

These are the headers I am attaching to HTTP PATCH request:
[image]

This is request body:
[image]

I've read on [this](http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/) website that POST requests need to contain bodies like that: [
    { "op": "replace", "path": "/email", "value": "new.email@example.org" }
]

If I provide a request body that you can see in the screenshot below, I still get the same response:

[image]

Here is class User that the table controller is based on:

```
public class User : EntityData
{
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

How should I properly send a Patch request via Postman?

Comment: how about using your second request, but sending `Gender` with capital **G** instead of small **g**. Your model defines `Gender`, not `gender` ?

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Comment: The semantics of application/json as PATCH payload are undefined; you should have a look at RFCs 6902 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902) and 7386 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7386).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use your second request but send the 'gender' property with a lowercase **g** instead of capital **G**. This is how you define this property in your model, JSON serializer/deserializer is case sensitive by default.